# How to change the color of an image in XNA

Tags: c#, .net, xna

I have a Texture2D that contains an semi-transparent white image... and I'm wondering how to change it to semi-transparent green programmatically.

Any help would be really appreciated.
j3d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's about:

```
batch.Draw(texture, myVector, Color.Green * 0.5f); //The float indicates the transparency of the green color
```

Comment: Ok but he should know that there is also this option.

Answer (score 1):

When you [draw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff433991.aspx) it, you can specify a colour:

```
batch.Draw(texture, Vector2.Zero, Color.Green);
```